# Error: Project 'server.js' does not support the 'serve' target

Tags: node.js, mean-stack, nodemon

I am a beginner to the MEAN stack framework. I am trying to run a node js server, using "nodemon server.js" command. But I get this error. I am trying to figure out why

```
Angular CLI: 9.1.3
Node: 12.4.0
Angular: 9.1.3
```

This is my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "Angular-App",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "start:server": "nodemon server.js"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^9.1.3",
    "@angular/common": "^9.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^9.1.3",
    "@angular/core": "^9.1.3",
    "@angular/fire": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^9.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^9.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^9.1.3",
    "@angular/router": "^9.1.3",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "firebase": "^7.14.2",
    "jquery": "^3.5.0",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^5.6.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.5",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.901.3",
    "@angular/cli": "^9.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^9.1.3",
    "@angular/language-service": "^9.1.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.3",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "^3.8.3"
  }
}
```

These are my versions
Please help, I am stuck in my project here

Comment: Post your `package.json`.

Comment: I found a solution to this. Thanks guys. I haven't been in the right directory when adding nodemon